# Use regexp_replace function for last 5 digits

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have values in column like "07960/WR" , "27163/WR", etc. I need to select all numbers from it. So i created sql:

> select CAST (regexp_replace(object_index, '\D', '', 'g') as integer) as number from ...

Its OK, but when somebody put [number] / <- slash / ....
example: "99/27163/WR"

My query doesnt work.

How to use regexp_replace ONLY for last 5 digits in value?

Comment: Do those last five digits always form an entire number, or could they be split into smaller numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PostgreSQL, but with a little help from RegexBuddy, I pieced something together that hopefully works:

```
select CAST (REGEXP_REPLACE(object_index, $$(?p)^.*(\d{5})\D*$$$, $$\1$$, 'g') as integer) as number from ...
```

The idea of this regex is to match and capture the last five digits `\d{5}` in the string (i. e. those that are followed only by non-digits: `\D*$`) and remove everything around them.